# GCC compilation error when inheriting constructors

Tags: c++, gcc

This code is compiled by gcc with an error

```
template<typename>
struct B {
};

template<typename... Types>
struct A : public B<Types>... {
    using B<Types>::B...;
    using B<Types>::operator=...;
}
```

compiler output

```
<source>:8:8: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'B'

    8 |  using B<Types>::operator=...;

      |   

 ^
```

But this code compiles without errors

```
template<typename>
struct B {
};

template<typename... Types>
struct A : public B<Types>... {
    using B<Types>::operator=...;
    using B<Types>::B...;
};
```

I can 't understand why this is happening.

---

**Update**

for gcc, constructor inheritance also breaks the code

```
template<typename T>
struct B {
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename... Types>
struct A : public B<Types>... {
    using B<Types>::B...;

    void bar() {
        (B<Types>::foo() , ...);
    }
};
```

Comment: `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: g++ with -std=c++17

Comment: Just making sure ;)

Comment: What version of GCC do you have?

Comment: Whatever version it is, error happens with the GCC 9.2 too

Comment: `g++` seems to complain all the way up to 9.3 and even trunk.

Comment: yes. all versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a GCC bug, that was fixed finally in GCC 11.

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/arxjPjTa5

Another demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KhjGn945G

Comment: Yes, it is fixed: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94310